# Inject components with dynamic id for multiple usage -Angular4

Tags: angular

I want to use the map.component  in my dynamic window.component for multiple times in different windows ( i get multiple dynamic windows  with a map inside by an click-event in the same application).

**window.component.html**

```
<jqxWindow>
    <div>
        <olmap></olmap>
    </div>
<jqxWindow>
```

**map.component.html**

```
<div id="map" class="map" ></div>
```

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as ol from 'openlayers';

@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  // template: '<div id={{mapId}}></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  mapId: string = "";
  map: ol.Map = undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.mapId = "map";
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
      })
    });
  }
}
```

But only in the first window gets the map rendered. The second, third,... window is empty.
Perhaps i need for every window a new map `id` or a completely different solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need for a dynamical use, a dynamical map-id.
In your map.components.ts you can build a random id for your map:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as ol from 'openlayers';

@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  // template: '<div id={{mapId}}></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  mapId: string = "";
  map: ol.Map = undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.mapId = "map" + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
      })
    });
  }
}
```

And your map.component.html should be look like:

```
<div  id={{mapId}} class="map"></div>
```

You should also check out 2 way data binding in angular...